# Divide times in two boxes and find the minimum difference

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Started to learn recursion and I am stuck with this simple problem. I believe that there are more optimized ways to do this but first I'm trying to learn the bruteforce approach.

I have bag A and bag B and have `n items` each one with some time (a float with two decimal places). The idea is to distribute the items by the two bags and obtain the minimum difference in the two bags. The idea is to try all possible outcomes.

I thought only in one bag (lets say bag A) since the other bag will contain all the items that are not in the bag A and therefore the difference will be the absolute value of total times sum - 2 * sum of the items time that are in the bag A.

I'm calling my recursive function like this:

```
min = total_time;
recursive(0, items_number - 1, 0);
```

And the code for the function is this:

```
void recursive(int index, int step, float sum) {
    sum += items_time[index];
    float difference = fabs(total_time - 2 * sum);

    if (min > difference) {
        min = difference;
    }

    if (!(min == 0.00 || step == 1 || sum > middle_time)) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < items_number; i++) {
            if (i != index) {
                recursive(i, step - 1, sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Imagine I have 4 items with the times `1.23, 2.17 , 2.95 , 2.31`

I'm getting the result `0.30`. I believe that this is the correct result but I'm almost certain that if it is is pure change because If I try with bigger cases the program stops after a while. Probably because the recursion tree gets to bigger.

Can someone point me in some direction?

Comment: What exactly are the `items_number` and `number_of_pizzas`? Also it would be nice to know what `middle_time` is, though I think it is the half of the `total_time`. Seeing the entire source code would also be really good.

Comment: Sorry. Made a mistake. It's `items_number` that is, the total amount of items. Four in the example I put. You're right. `middle_time` is the half of `total_time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after the clarification, let me (hopefully) point you to a direction:

Let's assume that you know what `n` is, mentioned in `n items`. In your example, it was `2n` is `4`, making `n = 2`. Let's pick another `n`, let it be `3` this time, and our `time`s shall be:

```
1.00
2.00
3.00
4.00
5.00
6.00
```

Now, we can already tell what the answer is; what you had said is all correct, optimally each of the bags will have their `n = 3` `time`s summed up to `middle_time`, which is `21 / 2 = 10.5` in this case. Since integers may never sum up to numbers with decimal points, `10.5 : 10.5` may never be achieved in this example, but `10 : 11` can, and you can have `10` through `6.00 + 3.00 + 1.00` (3 elements), so... yeah, the answer is simply `1`.

How would you let a computer calculate it? Well; recall what I said at the beginning:

> Let us assume that you know what **n** is.

In that case a naive programmer would probably simply put all those inside 2 or 3 nested `for` loops. `2` if he/she knew that the other half will be determined when you pick a half (by simply fixing the very first element in our group, since that element is to be included in one of the groups), like you also know; `3` if he/she didn't know that. Let's make it with `2`:

```
...
float difference;
int i;
for ( i = 1; i < items_number; i++ ) {
    sum = items_time[0] + items_time[i];
    int j;
    for ( j = i + 1; j < items_number; j++ ) {
        sum += items_time[j];
        difference = fabs( total_time - 2 * sum );
        if ( min > difference ) {
            min = difference;
        }
    }
}
...
```

Let me comment about the code a little for faster understanding: On the first cycle, it will add up the 0th time, the 1st time and then the 2nd time as you may see; then it will do the same check you had made (calculate the `difference` and compare the it with `min`). Let us call this the `012` group. The next group that will be checked will be `013`, then `014`, then `015`; then `023`, and so on... Each possible combination that will split the 6 into two 3s will be checked.

This operation shouldn't be any tiresome for the computer to issue. Even with this simple approach, the maximum amount of tries will be the amount of combinations of 3 you could have with 6 unique elements divided by 2. In maths, people denote this as `C(6, 3)`, which evaluates to `(6 * 5 * 4) / (3 * 2 * 1) = 20`; divided by 2, so it's `10`.

My guess is that the computer wouldn't make it a problem even if `n` was 10, making the amount of combinations as high as [`C(20, 10) / 2 = 92 378`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C%28+20+%2C+10+%29+%2F+2). It would, however, be a problem for you to write down 9 nested `for` loops by hand...

Anyway, the good thing is, you can recursively nest these loops. Here I will end my guidance. Since you apparently are studying for the recursion already, it wouldn't be good for me to offer a solution at this point. I can assure you that it is do-able.

Also the version I have made on my end can do it within a second for up to `items_number = 22`, without having made any optimizations; simply with brute force. That makes [`352 716`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C%28+22+%2C+11+%29+%2F+2) combinations, and my machine is just a simple Windows tablet...

Comment: First let me star by thanking you for this explanation. I'm having trouble in the second paragraph. You say that 2n is 4 making n = 4. Isn't n=2?

Comment: Thanks. Will now focus on the recursive part :(

Comment: @Favolas Exactly. Sorry, on the first run I had written something like *"n = 2 so 2n = 4"*; and I apparently have forgotten to change that on the way...

Comment: Another question. Since you're making for `n=2` shouldn't the second for (while on the first iteration `i = 1`) end at the group `013`?

Comment: @Favolas If I had made `n = 2`, there would be no second `for`, but only one `for`, which would check `01`, `02` and `03`; with `23`, `13` and `12` being the rest, respectively. However, starting with the sentence *"Let's pick another n, ..."*, I have started using `n = 3`, which requires me to use a second `for` loop, nested.

Comment: @Favolas You're welcome bro, hope you can do the recursion thing. Ask away if you ever get stuck though...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48193/discussion-between-favolas-and-thoappelsin)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is called the [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). It is NP-hard and after some point, it will take a **very** long time to complete: the tree gets exponentially bigger as the number of cases to test grows.

The partition problem is well known and well documented over the internet. There exists some optimized solution

Comment: Thanks, but the partition problem gives me if the set can be partitioned in two. It does not give me the minimum difference if it is not possible to divide equally in two

Comment: On wikipedia it says: "There is an optimization version of the partition problem, which is to partition the multiset S into two subsets S1, S2 such that the difference between the sum of elements in S1 and the sum of elements in S2 is minimized." It sounds like the problem you are trying to solve :)

Comment: Thanks. Now just have to find the algorithm explication. But nevertheless my recursive function it's not working as expected and I don't understand why

Comment: Again, the number of cases gets exponentially bigger. Usually when the problem is very small it takes an instant, then at some point it will take seconds, and then adding just one element will make it run *forever*.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not the naive brute-force approach, which would just walk through the list of items and put it into bag A and bag B recursively, chosing the case with the minimum difference, for example:

```
double recurse(double arr[], int n, double l, double r)
{
    double ll, rr;

    if (n == 0) return fabs(l - r);

    ll = recurse(arr + 1, n - 1, l + *arr, r);
    rr = recurse(arr + 1, n - 1, l, r + *arr);

    if (ll > rr) return rr;
    return ll;
}
```

(This code is *very* naive - it doesn't quite early on clearly non-optimal cases and it also wastes time by calculating every case twice with bags A and B swapped. it is brute force, however.)

You maximum recursion depth is the numer of items `n`, you call the recursive function `2^n - 1` times.

In your code, you can put the same item into a bag over and over:

```
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_pizzas; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            recursive(i, step - 1, sum);
        }
    }
```

This loop prevents you from treating the current item, but will happily treat items that have been put into the bag in earlier recursions for a second (or third) time. If you want to use that approach, you must keep a state of which item is in which bag.

Also, I don't understand your `step`. You start with `step - 1` and stop recursion when `step == 1`. That means you are considering `n - 2` items. I understand that the other items are in the other bag, but that's a weird condition that won't let you find the solution to, say, `{8.0, 2.4, 2.4, 2.8}`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I stop at `step == 1` because I don't want a solution with all of the items in the same bag. I thought that this would leave at least one item in the bag